# How to use AWS KMS with java sdk to be able to resolve IAM credentials into ECS env?

Tags: java, aws-sdk, amazon-iam, amazon-kms

I have a encryption service build with credentials

```
public AWSKMS kms() {
    final AWSKMSClientBuilder builder = AWSKMSClient.builder();

    if (!properties.getAccessKey().isEmpty() && !properties.getSecretKey().isEmpty()) {
        builder.withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(properties.getAccessKey(), properties.getSecretKey())));
    }

    if (Optional.ofNullable(properties.getEndpoint()).isPresent()) {
        builder.withEndpointConfiguration(new EndpointConfiguration(properties.getEndpoint().getServiceEndpoint(), properties.getEndpoint().getSigningRegion()));
    } else {
        Optional.ofNullable(properties.getRegion()).ifPresent(builder::setRegion);
    }

    return builder.build();
}
```

is it possible this service to retrieve the credentials from IAM role?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the creds you pulled with StS
You can then request to assume a role and your creds will get updated to one's with that roles permissions.

Some thing like,

> Samples:
>
> To assume a role
>      AssumeRole

```
    AWSSecurityTokenService client = AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder.standard().build();
    AssumeRoleRequest request = new AssumeRoleRequest().withRoleArn("arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/demo").withRoleSessionName("Bob")
            .withPolicy("{\"Version\":\"2012-10-17\",\"Statement\":[{\"Sid\":\"Stmt1\",\"Effect\":\"Allow\",\"Action\":\"s3:*\",\"Resource\":\"*\"}]}")
            .withDurationSeconds(3600).withExternalId("123ABC");
    AssumeRoleResult response = client.assumeRole(request);
```

AWS [outline it here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/securitytoken/AWSSecurityTokenService.html#assumeRole-com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.AssumeRoleRequest-) in the SDK for Java